# How to disable the transition animation between the splash and first frame of main in android? (SplashScreen API)

Tags: android

I have the same design for the splash screen *(android:windowSplashScreenBackground and android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon)* and for the *android:windowBackground.* But when the app switches between these two screens there is a flashing animation, so it is not smooth, it is visible that those are two separate things.

Is it possible to disable that transition animation somehow? I tried setting android:windowIsTranslucent to true and it works but I am afraid it would have some side-effects. Is there any other solution for this or is it safe to use windowIsTranslucent?

Note: This is a React-Native application, so I have no other activities beside the Main one, maybe that makes using windowIsTranslucent safer? I dont know